# swagger generation in mule with jetty

Tags: java, jetty, mule, swagger

I am trying to generate swagger from my apis.I am using mule and added this jetty connector for that. My mule server is running on 8080

```
 <jetty:connector name="jettyConnector">
        <jetty:webapps directory="${app.home}/webapps" port="8083"/>
    </jetty:connector>
```

I have added web .xml under src/main/app/webapps/swaggerdoc/WEB-INF/web.xml and the content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Swagger doc</display-name>
    <description>swagger doc</description>

    <servlet>
  <servlet-name>JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>api.version</param-name>
    <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:8002/api</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.rest.types.resource;com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And pom file has this dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

But after starting mule when I am hitting http://localhost:8080/api, its throwing "Not Authorized". I have used all annotations on the api's correctly.

Any help would be really appreciative. I am stuck on this problem from last few days.

Interface from which I am trying to generate swagger:

```
@Path("/api-docs")
@Api(value = "/transactions", description = "Update APIs")
public interface BaseResource {


    @PUT
    @ApiOperation(value = "updateTransactions", notes = "update Transaction.", httpMethod = "PUT")
    @ApiResponses({ @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED, message = "Accepted"),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, message = "Bad Request"),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, message = "Unauthorized "),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message = "Internal Server Error") })
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    BaseResource.PutTransactionsResponse updateTransactions(
            @ApiParam(name = "Authorization",
                    defaultValue = "",
                    required = true) @HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
            UpdateRequest entity)
            throws Exception;


}
```

MULE FLOW:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:jetty="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jetty"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey"
    xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking"
    xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jetty http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jetty/current/mule-jetty.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mule-app.properties" />


 <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="apiListingJSON"
            class="com.wordnik.swagger.mule.ApiListingJSON" />
        <spring:bean id="swaggerConfig"
            class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig">
            <spring:property name="resourcePackage" value="com.rest.types.resource" />
            <spring:property name="version" value="1.0.0" />
            <spring:property name="basePath" value="http://0.0.0.0:8080" />
            <spring:property name="scan" value="true" />
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>
<spring:beans>

        <spring:bean id="sampleResourceBean"
            class="com.rest.types.resource.UpdateApiImpl" />
    </spring:beans>


    <flow name="services_all" doc:name="services_all">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="0.0.0.0" port="8080" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log Incoming Request"/>

        <choice doc:name="ContextRootRouting">

            <when
                expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.request'] contains '/api-docs']">

                <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String" />
                <logger message="About to call Transaction Service, #[payload]"
                    doc:name="Logger" />
                 <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">     
         <component> 
            <spring-object bean="sampleResourceBean" />
        </component> 
         <component>
            <spring-object bean="apiListingJSON" />
        </component>
    </jersey:resources>
</when>            
</mule>
```

Comment: Can you include information about the file permissions on your system?

Comment: what type of file permission? I am running mule as sudo.

Comment: Your Jetty connector code seems to specify port 8083 instead of 8080. Should that be 8080?

Comment: I tried that one but since mule is running on 8080. It throws bind exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a mule-specific module with a tutorial and a sample in the swagger-core repository which does not depend/require jetty at all.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Mule-Project-Setup

The tutorial contains all the information you need including the dependency and link to the sample.

If possible, I'd opt for the 1.5 version found here - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Mule-Project-Setup-1.5 - even though the Mule module for that version is not yet published (but can be compiled from the develop_2.0 branch).

Comment: I tried first approach but getting this error: com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api.hidden()Z. followed this one: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Mule-Project-Setup

Comment: I'd need a bit more information - the full stack trace and the exact steps you took. If the project is public and can be viewed, that would also help.

Comment: That error is gone but I am not getting whole swagger file. I have update the class in my original question. But I am getting only this much JSON.          {
    "apiVersion": "1.0.0",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
    "apis": [
        {
            "path": "/transactions",
            "description": "update APIs"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: That's what you're supposed to get. If you hit `/api-docs/transactions` you'll get the detailed operations. You're good to go.

Comment: When I hit /api-docs/transactions, got this error. No serializer found for class com.wordnik.swagger.model.ApiListing and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ). I have added javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter file to service dir.

Comment: Sounds like something's possibly missing from the configuration. Can you please follow the guide again to make sure you took all the steps? The sample project should also serve as a reference.

Comment: I went through again. doing exact same as mentioned in that guide. this is the path  src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter for registering swagger-core? not sure what I am missing than?

Comment: Which Mule version do you use? Did you update the dependency to be the one for mule? The question contains the general jaxrs dependency.

Comment: I am using MULE 3.6.0-M2 and jersey is   <jersey.version>2.11</jersey.version> and using this swagger dependency: <dependency>
  <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-mule_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.12</version>
</dependency

Comment: That may be the reason. Mule 3.6 uses a much newer version of jersey. Try switching to the swagger-jersey2-jaxrs dependency.

Comment: and remove swagger-mule_2.10? what version of swagger-jersey2-jaxrs?

Comment: Yes, remove the swagger-mule dependency. You can use the same version.

Comment: I used this one  
I used this dependency <dependency> <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId> <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId> <version>1.3.12</version> </dependency>  But still getting No serializer found for class com.wordnik.swagger.model.ApiListing and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ). Not sure what is wrong now. deleted my repositry also before making new build.

Comment: I'd need to run tests locally.